# how do I create a "temporary" type inside a type, in order to be DRY?

Tags: typescript

I can't even know how to search in SO for this question. My generic type `FetchOptions` is actually this:

```
type FetchOptions<T> = {
  explode?: string & keyof T | (string & keyof T)[];
}
```

I can't find a way to create another type `string & keyof T` in order to avoid the repetition in the subsequent array definition and *without extracting the type* (inside the type itself):

```
type Key<T> = string & keyof T;

type Options<T> = {
  explode?: Key<T> | Key<T>[];
}
```

Example usage:

```
class Product {
  id: number | string;
  name: string;
  variants?: ProductVariant[];
  attributes?: ProductVariant[];
}

const fetchProducts = (options: FetchOptions<Product> = {}) => {
  // ...
};

fetchProducts({ explode: 'variants' });
fetchProducts({ explode: ['variants', 'attributes'] });
```

Comment: Why is creating that second type undesirable? Sometimes I find that libraries which don't expose the sub-types of larger composite types can occasionally be annoying to work with, making it difficult to construct objects from other variables containing their constituent parts. The generics trick mentioned by @TobiasS. is very handy, but makes for code that is much harder to read at first glance, and w/o piling on additional constraints it could go very wrong for the consumer (conversely, adding them further increases the cognitive load on the consumer). KISS for the win IMO.

Comment: @spender good point.. I'm studying the language, that's why I asked. I'll go for the extra type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I often see additional generic parameters with *default values* used to avoid repetition.

```
type FetchOptions<T, E = string & keyof T> = {
  explode?: E | E[];
}
```

When used like `FetchOptions<Product>`, you get the same behaviour as before. But you may have to worry about accidentally providing a second generic parameter. `E` is not constraint, so any type could be passed to `FetchOptions`.

We can add a constraint which would guarantee the correct type.

```
type FetchOptions<T, E extends string & keyof T = string & keyof T> = {
  explode?: E | E[];
}
```

But since this makes us type out the type twice, it is probably only useful if the type is used more often.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYlEBjAFgeQiAlgewHYDOAPACoA0MAojALwwEgBOWeA5jAGQwDWUYOAMxgkAfLRgBvYDBhQAHhAA2OACZQA-AC4qMAD5UA2gF0A3MAC+wYEkUBDAgRgAFRqoCuSEJOkwsKgITaeG4AtgBGUIx69EwsrGYyeLYhUIExzGwJMAButsy2eCAEWpLmxlm2ILFhbiBQxdoSZaYWVkj4DDACiKgu7p6OdAAUOJi4hNoIyOhjHUR9Kh4gYnRNAJS0YlIyAPQ7MAB0RxZmwN3TC0sEQxKyCspq2gDkufmFBE8w5mtm572uiwGNzuSlUUG0BheeSwBSKTwoT0q1Vq9SeRi+PyAA)

Comment: Oh.. that's cool. I second that too, and honestly a second generic parameter just to avoid DRY isn't a good solution imho. What's the possibile use cases of the second parameter?

Comment: @gremo -  You mean in general or in this example? Here, it let's us declare a kind of local type which can be populated by the other generic parameters. Probably not the intended use case of default type parameters. But you often see it.

Comment: Sorry I mean: what could be a possible usage of the second parameter, apart from being dry in type definition? Basically providing the second parameter would be always useless - if not dangerous, right?

Comment: @gremo - There is no extra use apart from potentially making the code shorter. And yes, someone could mess up the type by providing a wrong second generic argument.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve something like a 'scoped type' with `infer`.
No additional parameters required in the main generic type.
It is also boasts more flexibility in a complex expression since it does not only rely on the type parameters but can use any types that have recently been inferred.

```
type FetchOptions<T> =
  (string & keyof T) extends (infer E) ?
  // scope starts
   { explode?: E | E[]; } :
  // scope ends
  never;
```